# In top Level of a script, is LexicalEnvironment the same as VariableEnvironment

Tags: javascript, scope, executioncontext

I have browsed many similar questions and ECMA262 2022 for some days, but still don't know why.

1. I know LE is the same as VE originally, does it means that they point to one Environment Record.
2. in the top level of the script, if contains `let` or `const` declarations, will a new Environment Record be created and LE point to it?

Am I right to think it as following?

```
let a = 1
var b = 2
console.log(a)
---------------------------
// Pseudo code：
// which right? or other else

global Execution Context = {
  VE: {
    bindings: b
    [[outerEnv]]: null
  },
// create a new ER whose [[outerEnv]] is null. then LE point to it.
  LE: {
    bindings: a
    [[outerEnv]]: null
  }
}
```

or

```
global Execution Context = {
  VE: {
    bindings: b
    [[outerEnv]]: null
  },
// create a new ER whose [[outerEnv]] is the original ER (which the unchangeable VE point to)
// then LE point to it
  LE: {
    bindings: a
    [[outerEnv]]: VE
  }
}
```